# MIDI music support in HTML5

Tags: html, audio, midi

Now playing midi in html is supported with javascript and windows media player/quicktime browser plugins. 
I'm wondering if there are any news about html5 is going to support playing midi with audio tag in the future ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to play midi files, you can see how they did it here:
http://mudcu.be/midi-js/.
The example page makes use of [MIDI.js](https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js). Note that it even uses soundfonts, all via scripting. Pretty neat.

If you're more interested in controlling midi devices, or having midi devices control your HTML5 page: the W3C guys are working on that. See the [draft api description here](http://webaudio.github.io/web-midi-api/)

Comment: MIDI.js still has a remaining bug that needs to be fixed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74954880/settimeout-triggers-too-late-in-midi-js

Answer (score 2):

With [html-midi-player](https://github.com/cifkao/html-midi-player), it is possible to embed a MIDI file in a website simply by inserting a `midi-player` element (a custom HTML element which works a lot like the `audio` element, but for MIDI files):

```html
<midi-player src="jazz.mid" sound-font></midi-player>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Complete demo:

```html
<midi-player src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cifkao/html-midi-player@2b12128/jazz.mid" sound-font>
</midi-player>

<!-- The following needs to be inserted somewhere on the page for the player(s) to work. -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/combine/npm/tone@14.7.58,npm/@magenta/music@1.22.1/es6/core.js,npm/focus-visible@5,npm/html-midi-player@1.4.0"></script>
```

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of html-midi-player.*