# How to play MIDI file in base64 in HTML?

Tags: html, midi

I have found a website and generated some MIDI base64 string:

```
data:audio/midi;base64,TVRoZAAAAAYAAAABAeBNVHJrAAAA5wD/WAQEAhgIAP9RAwehIADAAADAAGWQXH8AwABlgFx/AMAAZZBZfwDAAGWAWX8AwABlkFZ/AMAAZYBWfwDAAGWQQ38AkEF/AJBCfwCQQH8AkD9/AMlPAJlPfwDAAACQU38AwABlgEN/AMAAZYBCfwDAAGWAP38AwABlgFN/AMAAZZBDfwDJTwCZT38AwAAAkFB/AMAAZYBBfwDAAGWJT38AwABliQB/AMAAZcAAZYBAfwDAAGWAUH8AwABlkE1/AMAAZYBDfwDAAGXAAGWATX8AwABlwABlwABlwABlwABlkDh/AP8vAA==
```

But I found it's not able to play via the `audio` tag. Is it possible for me to play that?

Comment: You can use this jquery plugin https://github.com/rism-ch/midi-player and check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168093/midi-music-support-in-html5

Answer (score 1):

use
https://github.com/surikov/webaudiofont
the project consists of 2000 digitized instrument and examples for produce single wave, chord, melody, midi file.

Answer (score 0):

You can play midi base64 strings with this javascript library https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js
The *MIDI Player* code example does exact what you want.

when i do

```js
player.loadFile(MIDI_BASE64_STRING, player.start);
```

I can hear the sound of the song. The .mid file is hardcoded into a base64 string named MIDI_BASE64_STRING in the code.

Comment: Please describe the details in the body of your answer.